# Access Neo4j browser for Rails application

Tags: neo4j, ruby-on-rails-5

I've set up a very basic Rails/Neo4j application to play around with following something like the example instructions from http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.x/Setup.html, i.e.

```
rails new myapp -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
cd myapp
rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
rake neo4j:start

rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
rake neo4j:migrate
```

Then in a Rails console:

```
user = User.new(:name => 'Bob', :email => 'bob@bob.com')
user.save
User.count
 HTTP REQUEST: 12ms GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint (0 bytes)
 HTTP REQUEST: 3ms GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index (0 bytes)
 CYPHER 
  MATCH (n:`User`)
  RETURN count(n) AS count 
 HTTP REQUEST: 110ms POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit (1 bytes)
=> 1
```

This all looks fine and http://localhost:3000/users shows the new user as expected. But, if I go to http://localhost:7474 there's no sign of anything; Neo4j informs me that there are no labels or relationships in the database. Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but it seems that using localhost:7474 (in Safari) produces the problems discussed above, whereas 127.0.0.1:7474 is fine. Everything else I've been running recently (e.g. SOLR, Rails, Django) is fine with localhost.